# Apache Weblog Parsing using regex. Which is better, case class or a Java like class?

Tags: regex, scala

I am writing a general scala class which can parse the apache weblog files. So far the solution I have is to use group regex to match the different parts of the log string.To illustrate each line of the incoming logs gives something like the string below

*25.198.250.35 - - [2014-07-19T16:05:33Z] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1081 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"*

```
class HttpLogStringParser(logLine: String) {
  // Regex Pattern matching the logLine
  val pattern = """^([\d.]+) (\S+) (\S+) \[(.*)\] \"(.+?)\" (\d{3}) (\d+) \"(\S+)\" \"([^\"]+)\"$""".r
  val matched = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(logLine)

  def getIP: String = {
    val IP = matched match {
      case Some(m) => m.group(1)
      case _ => None
    }
    IP.toString
  }

  def getTimeStamp: String = {
    val timeStamp = matched match {
      case Some(m) => m.group(4)
      case _ => None
    }
    timeStamp.toString
  }

  def getRequestPage: String = {
    val requestPage = matched match {
      case Some(m) => m.group(5)
      case _ => None
    }
    requestPage.toString
  }

  def getStatusCode: String = {
    val statusCode = matched match {
      case Some(m) => m.group(6)
      case _ => None
    }
    statusCode.toString
  }
}
```

calling these methods should give me IP, date, timestamp or status code. Is this the best way to do it. I have also tried pattern matching on case class but that just gives me match boolean. Am I getting it completely wrong. what would be the best way to get the values I need from the input log string?

Answer (score 1):

See the docs:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.matching.Regex

You can drop the anchors from the pattern and do:

```
val (a, b, c) = line match { case p(x, _, y, z) => (x, y, z) case _ => ??? }
```

where p is your Regex.

Or use `(?:foo)` or otherwise remove groups that aren't of interest.

You can also use `Regex.Groups` to extract groups from a `Match`.

Otherwise, it doesn't matter terribly much.

Move the Regex to the companion object so it's compiled only once.